# Select a div based on it's child's selector?

Tags: jquery

first time long time.
Trying to select certain elements in a feed based on this selector that some of their children contain. The child div (buried way down in divs within divs) in question looks like this:

```
<div data-test-id="example-test-id">
...
</div>
```

Their parent divs look like this:

```
<div data-grid-item="true">
...
</div>
```

I want to select any div whose `data-grid-item="true"`, who also contains a child div whose `data-test-id="example-test-id"` .

Resulting in code that looks like this:

```
{$("div[data-grid-item='true']:has(data-test-id="example-test-id"])").css( "background-color", "red" )}
```

In this case I'm just trying to give the parent div a red background so I can verify that I've selected the correct elements, which doesn't seem to be working. As I'm sure you can tell, I'm a novice at jquery so the above code is what I've been able to glean from lots of googling. Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: your jquery looks right, except for the quotes. You have double quotes around the selector and inside it. Put single quotes around `example-test-id`.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a typo, you were so close :

```
$("div[data-grid-item='true']:has(data-test-id="example-test-id"])")
__________________________________^ Missing '['
```

**Note:** The double quotes are also part of the problem you need to replace then by single ones like :

```
$("div[data-grid-item='true']:has([data-test-id='example-test-id'])")
________________________________________________^_______________^
```

```js
$("div[data-grid-item='true']:has([data-test-id='example-test-id'])").css("background-color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-grid-item="true">
  <div data-test-id="example-test-id">TEST 1</div>
</div>
<div data-grid-item="true">
  <div>TEST 2</div>
</div>
<div data-grid-item="true">
  <div data-test-id="example-test-id">TEST 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If it's just a typo, shouldn't this be voted close due to typo?

Comment: Go ahead and flag it, that doesn't mean not showing the right answer.

Comment: Oh I was more on the topic of a typo question should be closed and not answered, yes your answer is most likely correct